# How to assign i by value to objects in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var doors = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    var door = new Door();
    door.setDoorNumber(i);
    doors.push(door);
};
```

The door implementation is this:

```
Door = function(){

var doorNumber;

Door.prototype.getDoorNumber = function(){
    return doorNumber; 
};
Door.prototype.setDoorNumber = function(number){
    doorNumber = number;
};
```

The output is this:

```
door[0].getDoorNumber(); // 99
door[1].getDoorNumber(); // 99
door[2].getDoorNumber(); // 99
door[3].getDoorNumber(); // 99
```

I want the output to be this:

```
door[0].getDoorNumber(); // 0
door[1].getDoorNumber(); // 1
door[2].getDoorNumber(); // 2
door[3].getDoorNumber(); // 3
```

What's the deal?  I am assuming this is because in js `i` is being passed by reference.  What is the best way to get my desired output?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, to answer my own question, I should have used this.getDoorNumber() instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  By the way, please don't say "like everything else is passed by reference".  Everything in JavaScript is passed _by value_ (even objects, because in JavaScript object references are passed by value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're just creating a new variable and assigning 0 through 99 to that variable. It's not a property of the `Door` object.

Just qualify it with `this` to make it work.

```
Door = function(){
    this.doorNumber;
}

Door.prototype.getDoorNumber = function(){
    return this.doorNumber; 
};
Door.prototype.setDoorNumber = function(number){
    this.doorNumber = number;
};
```

Comment: Why the strange constructor implementation?  Were you trying to make the constructor accept an argument and store it in the `doorNumber` property?  Granted, that's what the OP _should_ have done....

Comment: No reason, I just copy pasted OPs original code. He might have wanted to do something like that and just put up a cleaned up simpler example.